# how to call a particular function in another class

Tags: iphone

hi i am new to iphone. what i need is i have to call a function named (void)mymethod from classA to classB. how can i call pls post some code thank u in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make Sure you have declared the `previousCallMethod` in MyPreviousClass.h file also.

```
MyPreviousClass *objMyPreviousClass = [[MyPreviousClass alloc] init];
[objMyPreviousClass previousClassMethod];
```

in your case (In ClassB)

```
ClassA *objClassA = [[ClassA alloc] init];
[objClassA mymethod];
```

But in this case also make sure you have declared `mymethod` in `ClassA.h`

hAPPY cODING...

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an object and then you can call a method on it. For example, you could have this in classA.

```
ClassB *object = [[ClassB alloc] init];
[object mymethod];
```

Comment: this gives a warning classA may not respond to mymethod,and in console it displays Application tryed to push nil view